# Multilayer Perceptron Weka

Tags: neural-network

I am brand new to data mining and to Weka. I have downloaded a .csv file onto Weka and I have been asked the following question: "Use a multilayer perceptron (MLP) in Weka with 50% test data. How well does the MLP reproduce the prices in the test data?"

This is what I do: I click on the CLASSIFY tab at the top of the Weka page and then I select the PERCENTAGE SPLIT radio button and type in "50%". I then click start. I get a huge set of information as a result. At the bottom of this wall of text, I see the following:

```
      Correlation coefficient ---   0.5767;
      Mean absolute error     ---   19.2052;
      Root mean squared error ---   23.7976;
      Relative absolute error ---   105.9793%;
      Root relative squared error-- 105.7659%;
      Total number of instances --- 2193.
```

Regarding the question "How well does MLP reproduce the prices", am I right in thinking that the answer is 57.67% (ie. the coefficient correlation is the answer)?

Comment: Could you provide the usr to the csv file?. but yes, I think that you need the "Correlation coefficient" because it shows you how much your calculated data fits to the real data, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CorrelationCoefficient.html

Comment: but think, is your reorder your data rows the result could be other, and other, so yo need to calculate the median of all correlation coefficients